# Iotify - Creating IoT devices to do GET requests to a local server using IoTify.io

Tags: simulation, iot, ddos

I am trying to DDoS a local server on my PC in order to test out some anti-DDoS methods on my local server. I am trying to simulate several IoT devices that will do a http GET request to my server on loop, trying to attck the server, I have already written the code (a simple js GET request) and it does work on a physical IoT Device. I need to scale it up to multiple in an IoT network environment, and I have been trying to use IoTify.io, but i cant quite understand the template creation phase. Can someone explain or point me at a tutorial/documentation that could help. P.S. I have read through the documentation provided already and I do require more Info. Thank you.